# Creating Sessionless page in Stripes

Tags: session, stripes, session-less

I have a Stripes website and I will have one page that will get lots of hits, and I was asked to make sure Stripes does not create a user session when someone navigates to this page.

Is there a way to make sure does not create a session when a user goes to a certain action?

Comment: Have you tried including `<%@ page session="false" %>` in the JSP?

Comment: Yes.  It has already created a session before it gets to the page.

Comment: The session is created by the servlet container.  Why do you not want the user to have a session?  You don't have to *do* anything with it. Is it an issue of preventing any cookies from being sent out?

Comment: I believe I was asked to prevent sessions from being made as a memory issue.  I do not know if the my boss is accurate that the creation of the sessions will drain resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an Interceptor and when ever action is been called for which you don't want to create session.. just look if response have 'SET-Cookie' in header, If it is remove that header content. I hope your problem will get solved.

regards
kishor

Comment: I'm not sure if this worked.  I sort of moved on from the problem.